# Efficient algorithm to generate a kind of maze

Tags: algorithm

I have done a lot of searching for this and have found lots of help to generate a maze, but I have a very specific requirement and all the loops Iv tried have failed horribly.

I created an editor where I could *draw* what I need, but a generator would help a great deal and this has failed.

**Requirement:**

Given a square grid of DIV elements (no smaller than 10x10 and no larger than 60x60) I need a joined path through and around the grid that will not touch itself at any point except at start/finish.
There must always be at least one blank square between all path squares (any number of blanks is fine so long as the path never comes into contact with itself).
There can be no dead ends and no loops (Where the path would cross itself).

This is kind of like a reverse maze - I *do not* need to fill the entire grid, in fact I have no problem with lots of space around the path. It might be easier to think of this along similar lines to a *Monopoly board game where the path around the board wanders about instead of going around the edges*. I'm actually stuck for an adequate description, hence calling it a reverse maze.

**Things I tried:**

Lots and lots of overly complex loops. Iv not really come very close and the issue is also one of performance.
Lots and lots of code designed to generate a maze. Some of these have been very good indeed, but they all generate a typical maze, which is not what I need at all really, and adapting the code has proven trickier than writing an insane set of loops within loops.

Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

**Update Code**

Okay, I have translated KIKO's PHP code into Javascript but somewhere along the line I have made a simple error that I cannot track down: The code works and generates a table of the correct dimensions and generates a path through it.

However, in the function "isWithinGrid" I have to subtract 1 from the width and height of the table or the entire thing will fail, and, if I do this, the code will work and created a path through the table minus *one* cell which will be incorrectly colored although clearly a part of the path.

Note that sometimes the path will be broken or touching itself. I have little doubt that some small problem is causing all of this, but currently this is the best I have come up with and any further help would be much appreciated.

```js
class Grid{
 constructor(width,height){    
  this.width  = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.cells = [];
  for(var x=0; x < this.width; x++){
   var tmparray = [];
   for(var y=0; y < this.height; y++){
    tmparray.push(false);
   }
   this.cells.push(tmparray);
  }
 }
 isWithinGrid(x,y){
  return (x >= 0) && (x <= this.width-1) && (y >= 0) && (y <= this.height-1);
 }
 isWithinPath(x,y){
  return this.isWithinGrid(x,y) && this.cells[x][y];
 }  
 setCellInPath(x,y,boolean){
  this.cells[x][y] = boolean;
  return this;
 }
 drawHorizontalLine(x1,x2,y){
  for(var x=x1; x < x2; x++){
   this.setCellInPath(x,y,true);
  }   
  return this;
 }
 drawVerticalLine(x,y1,y2){
  for(var y=y1; y < y2; y++){
   this.setCellInPath(x,y,true);
  } 
  return this;
 }
 drawSquare(){
  var left   = Math.round(this.width/5);
  var right  = Math.round(4*this.width/5);
  var top    = Math.round(this.height/5);
  var bottom = Math.round(4*this.height/5);
  this.drawHorizontalLine(left,right,top)
  .drawHorizontalLine(left,right,bottom)
  .drawVerticalLine(left,top,bottom)
  .drawVerticalLine(right,top,bottom);
  return this;
 }
 moveCell(x,y,dx,dy){
  this.setCellInPath(x,y,false);
  this.setCellInPath(x+dx,y+dy,true);
 }
 canMoveCell(x,y,dx,dy){
  return this.isWithinPath(x,y) &&
  this.isWithinGrid(x+dx,y+dy) &&
  !this.isWithinPath(x+dx,y+dy) &&
  !this.isWithinPath(x+2*dx,y+2*dy) &&
  !this.isWithinPath(x+dy+dx,y+dx+dy)
  !this.isWithinPath(x-dy+dx,y-dx+dy);
 }

 tryToDistortOnce(x,y,dx,dy){
  if (!this.canMoveCell(x,y,dx,dy)) return false;
  if (!this.canMoveCell(x+dy,y+dx,dx,dy)) return false;
  if (!this.canMoveCell(x-dy,y-dx,dx,dy)) return false;
  this.moveCell(x,y,dx,dy);
  this.setCellInPath(x+dy+dx,y+dx+dy,true);
  this.setCellInPath(x-dy+dx,y-dx+dy,true);
  return true;
 }
 distortOnce(){
  var x=0, y=0, dx=0, dy=0;
  do {
   x = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.width) + 1;
   y = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.height) + 1;
  } while (!this.isWithinPath(x,y));
  switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1){
   case 1: dx = -1; dy = 0; break;
   case 2: dx = +1; dy = 0; break;
   case 3: dx = 0; dy = +1; break;
   case 4: dx = 0; dy = -1; break;
  }
  if (this.tryToDistortOnce(x,y,dx,dy)){
   do {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
   } while (this.tryToDistortOnce(x,y,dx,dy));
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
 distortPath(numberOfDistortions = 10){
  for(var counter=1; counter < numberOfDistortions; counter++){
   var tries = 0;
   while (!this.distortOnce() && (tries < this.width+this.height)){ tries++; }
  }
  return this;
 }
 renderGrid(){
  var str = '<table class="TSTTAB">';  
  for(var y=0; y < this.width; y++){
   for(var x=0; x < this.height; x++){
    str += '<td'+(this.cells[y][x] ? ' class="path">' : '>');
   }
   str += '</tr>';
  }
  str += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML =str;
  return this;
 }
}
var Testgrid = new Grid(20,20);
Testgrid.drawSquare().distortPath(10).renderGrid();
```

```css
.TSTTAB{background-color:#7F7F7F;border-collapse:collapse;}
.TSTTAB td{ width:20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000;background-color: #E5E5E5; }
.TSTTAB td.path { background-color: #44F; }
```

```html
<div id='cont'></div>
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Idea: Start from the starting point, move randomly. If you're stuck, backtrack.

Comment: @connexo I don't think it would be useful as this is an algorithm question.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is a "blank square"?

Comment: In this case I think an algorithm that starts a path and moves randomly, then backtracks when stuck, can take very long and be rather unsuccessful. I would use another approach: Choose a start and end point between which a direct path is drawn. Select a random square out of the path and drag it in an random direction, while keeping the path connected, until it can go no further. This way you distort the path as much, or as little, as you want. I know, the devil is in the details, but perhaps this gives you new inspiration?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys:
I kind of tried the backtracking thing inside some pretty hefty loops, which is why I'm not posting them here and the biggest problem, other than it not working, was the time it takes.
@KIKOSoftware: I kind of get where you're going but I cant see how to implement that without getting stuck back into time consuming loops.

Comment: Well, it's gonna take me a while to work it out in more detail. Let me give it a try, it's quite an enjoyable little exercise.

Comment: Is there a required random distribution of the paths?

Comment: The kind of path you're looking for is technically called a "Labyrinth" -- like a maze except there's only one way to go.  One way to make one is to generate a maze and then trace around the walls.

Comment: @MattTimmermansP: A "Labyrinth"! Of course! The name is simple once its in front of me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've given it a try. One hour of work seems more than enough for a simple question. It is, of course, far from perfect, but it illustrates what I was talking about. It generates solutions like this:

[image: Example of a 20x20 grid with a complexity of 20]

The complete code is:

```
<?php

// error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// configuration
const SIZE_X     = 20;
const SIZE_Y     = 20;
const COMPLEXITY = 20;

// grid class
class Grid
{

  public function __construct($width,$height)
  {
    // remember
    $this->width  = $width;
    $this->height = $height;
    // initiate grid
    foreach (range(1,$width) as $x) {
      foreach (range(1,$height) as $y) {
        $this->cells[$x][$y] = FALSE;  // false means: not in path
      }
    }
  }

  public function isWithinGrid($x,$y)
  // testb whether (x,y) is within the grid
  {
    return ($x >= 1) && ($x <= $this->width) &&
           ($y >= 1) && ($y <= $this->height);
  }

  public function isWithinPath($x,$y)
  // is a cell part of the path?
  {
    return $this->isWithinGrid($x,$y) && $this->cells[$x][$y];
  }

  public function setCellInPath($x,$y,$boolean)
  // remember whether a cell is part of the path or not
  {
    $this->cells[$x][$y] = $boolean;
    return $this;
  }

  public function drawHorizontalLine($x1,$x2,$y)
  // simple horizontal line
  {
    foreach (range($x1,$x2) as $x) $this->setCellInPath($x,$y,TRUE);
    return $this;
  }

  public function drawVerticalLine($x,$y1,$y2)
  // simple vertical line
  {
    foreach (range($y1,$y2) as $y) $this->setCellInPath($x,$y,TRUE);
    return $this;
  }

  public function drawSquare()
  // simple square
  {
    $left   = round($this->width/5);
    $right  = round(4*$this->width/5);
    $top    = round($this->height/5);
    $bottom = round(4*$this->height/5);
    $this->drawHorizontalLine($left,$right,$top)
         ->drawHorizontalLine($left,$right,$bottom)
         ->drawVerticalLine($left,$top,$bottom)
         ->drawVerticalLine($right,$top,$bottom);
    return $this;
  }

  private function moveCell($x,$y,$dx,$dy)
  // move a cell
  {
    $this->setCellInPath($x,$y,FALSE);
    $this->setCellInPath($x+$dx,$y+$dy,TRUE);
  }

  private function canMoveCell($x,$y,$dx,$dy)
  // answers the question whether or not we can move (x,y) by (dx,dy)
  {
    return $this->isWithinPath($x,$y) &&                   // must be part of path
           $this->isWithinGrid($x+$dx,$y+$dy) &&           // stay within grid
           !$this->isWithinPath($x+$dx,$y+$dy) &&          // but not on the path
           !$this->isWithinPath($x+2*$dx,$y+2*$dy) &&      // and don't touch path
           !$this->isWithinPath($x+$dy+$dx,$y+$dx+$dy) &&  // and don't touch path
           !$this->isWithinPath($x-$dy+$dx,$y-$dx+$dy);    // and don't touch path
  }

  private function tryToDistortOnce($x,$y,$dx,$dy)
  {
    // this one should be able to move
    if (!$this->canMoveCell($x,$y,$dx,$dy)) return FALSE;
    // but also its neighbours must be able to move
    if (!$this->canMoveCell($x+$dy,$y+$dx,$dx,$dy)) return FALSE;
    if (!$this->canMoveCell($x-$dy,$y-$dx,$dx,$dy)) return FALSE;
    // move the target cell by displacement
    $this->moveCell($x,$y,$dx,$dy);
    // move neighbours by adding two cells
    $this->setCellInPath($x+$dy+$dx,$y+$dx+$dy,TRUE);
    $this->setCellInPath($x-$dy+$dx,$y-$dx+$dy,TRUE);
    return TRUE; // success!
  }

  private function distortOnce()
  // distort a random cell, returns success or failure
  {
    // find a random cell in path
    do {
      $x = rand(1,$this->width);
      $y = rand(1,$this->height);
    } while (!$this->isWithinPath($x,$y));
    // choose one of four directions to move in
    switch (rand(1,4))
    {
      case 1: $dx = -1; $dy = 0; break;
      case 2: $dx = +1; $dy = 0; break;
      case 3: $dx = 0; $dy = +1; break;
      case 4: $dx = 0; $dy = -1; break;
    }
    // try to do it
    if ($this->tryToDistortOnce($x,$y,$dx,$dy))
    {
      // more moves
      do {
        $x += $dx;
        $y += $dy;
      } while ($this->tryToDistortOnce($x,$y,$dx,$dy));
      return TRUE; // it was a success!
    }
    return FALSE; // we failed
  }

  public function distortPath($numberOfDistortions = 10)
  // distort up to a certain amount of times
  {
    // find a random cell that is part of the path to distort
    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $numberOfDistortions; $counter++) {
      // we try that a limited number of times, depending on the grid size
      $tries = 0;
      while (!$this->distortOnce() &&
             ($tries < $this->width+$this->height)) { $tries++; }
    }
    return $this;
  }

  public function renderGrid()
  // render grid
  {
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><style>'.
         '  td { width:20px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #000; }'.
         '  .path { background-color: #44F; }'.
         '</style></head><body><table>';
    foreach (range(1,SIZE_Y) as $y) {
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach (range(1,SIZE_X) as $x) {
        echo '<td'.($this->cells[$x][$y] ? ' class="path">' : '>');
      }
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</body></html></table>';
    return $this;
  }

}

// create grid
$grid = new Grid(SIZE_X,SIZE_Y);
// start with a square, distort and then render
$grid->drawSquare()
     ->distortPath(COMPLEXITY)
     ->renderGrid();
```

There are lots of things you can do to improve on this.... have fun!

On my server this code takes between 2 and 5 milliseconds to execute. Mileage may vary...

Comment: An excellent result, many thanks, but I was after Javascript or jQuery rather than PHP! Ill have a bash at a conversion today if I get a chance and Ill come back to let you know how it goes! Many thanks for the effort.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't aware of that. There's nothing that should stop you from turning this into Javascript. I also used a table instead of divs. It's all about the idea. To create more variation you could, for instance, make the starting rectangle more random, vary how far a single distortion goes, or make some distortions wider.

Comment: Well, it seems that my PHP is not up to scratch to convert this. I thought it looked easy enough but I cant get my head around the table cells at all and I'm struggling with the entire drawSquare() function.

I have a DIV grid rather than a table so it should be easy enough to change a class in order to add borders to the DIV's on the path and not to the others, but I cannot get the way to cross over between tables and DIV's.

The result is pretty much exactly what I need and I have a kind of idea of what I need to do, but things are not working out and I'm getting hung up on loops again!

Comment: Yes, programming requires a lot of knowledge: HTML, CSS, PHP, Javascript, JQuery, etc. No-one can know everything. Could you show me what you've got so far? Just add it to your question, or temporarily add it as an answer. Perhaps I can solve your Javascript-table-div conversion problem? Please make it as complete as possible... so it can at least run and do something.

Comment: Sorry for the delay KIKO, life and work is getting in the way of fun right now - Ill get back on this as soon as I'm able.

Comment: OK, not a problem, I can wait. Just remember that I sometimes check SO often, and sometimes not for a long time. So I might not respond quickly.

Comment: Not a worry KIKO, I'm flying by the seat of my pants myself right now. A quick stop over: I am trying to convert and stick with the table for now, but I'm struggling to work out where the "cells" in "$this->cells" comes from. It never seems to be created and the table itself is not created until the end, so I'm a bit lost. Code wont run unless I create "cells" as something and an array does not seem to work.

Comment: The cells array is initiated in the `__construct()` method of the Grid class. It's a 2D array of size width by height filled with `FALSE`, so it's basically empty (= no path). When a cell is set to 'TRUE' it is part of the path.

Comment: Added some code above to show where I am so far - its all working, kind of, but there is something small that I cant sort out.